# User management with role and type in firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am using angularfire2. I want to know the method which manages the user with role and type.
Here is my user json data.

```js
"users": {
  "12321323432": {
   "email": "admin@gmail.com",
   "type": "staff1",
   "role": "admin"
  },
  "354323432": {
   "email": "test@gmail.com",
   "type": "staff2",
   "role": "user"
  }
 }
```

And I want to manage the users table with user's role and type.
Otherwise the users table can be edited by the user who has admin role in the same type. If the user's role is admin and his type's different with the target user's one, he can't edit the target user table.

In the rules, I tried like that.

```js
"users": {
  "$uid": {
    ".write": (root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('role') === 'admin') && (root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('type') === newData.child('type'))
  }
}
```

But when publish the rules, I got this message.
"newData is invalid in .write expressions."

Comment: It is better to use custom tokens to set user roles: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdks

Comment: Firebase just launched support for role based access via custom user claims on the ID token: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims